# Activar o desactivar checkbox con React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de resolver en un checkbox un activado o desactivado. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal; necesito pasar cada vez que se active el checkbox a `true` y cuando se desactive a `false`. ¿Podrían apoyarme?

Este es el código que tengo:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
checkedFilter: true,});

const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {};

<FormGroup row>
    <FormControlLabel
        {...register(
            "cashier_admin"
        )}
        control={
            <Checkbox
                checked={
                    state.checkedFilter
                }
                onChange={
                    handleCheckboxChange
                }
                name="administrator"
            />
        }
        label={"Administrador"}
        key={"admin-option-key"}
    />
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: tu funcion ``handleCheckboxChange`` retorna ``{}``, lo correcto seria algo 
 que esa funcion setee el estado, algo como ``const handleCheckboxChange = e => {setState({state.checkedFilter: e.target.value})};``

Comment: Muchas gracias @AgustinG. pero cuando aplico esto  `const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
        setState({[state.checkedFilter]: e.target.value, })};` si me descativa el checkbox pero ya no lo vuelve a **ACTIVAR**  ya no pasa a true

Comment: Creo que te falte agregar ``value={state.checkedFilter}`` al <Checkbox> pero no estoy seguro. Si armas un pequeño ejemplo en un codesandbox o algo asi te lo puedo intentar resolver, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te aconsejo que separes tus variables en diversos hooks useState, esto te ahorrara muchos problemas en un futuro utilizando componentes de función y la vez hará que tus variables de estado sean mucho más faciles de manejar y modificar.

Por lo que yo solucionaria tu problema de la siguiente manera:

```
const [checkedFilter, setCheckedFilter] = useState(true);

const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
  setCheckedFilter(!checkedFilter)
};
```

Y tu checkbox:

```
<Checkbox checked={checkedFilter} onChange={handleCheckboxChange} name="administrator" />
```

Saludos, espero que te ayude.

Lectura recomendada:
https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que editar el handler para que cambie el estado con su hook, creo que el problema que tienes es en cómo estás asignando el estado, cuando haces `setState` ya estás haciendo referencia a `state`, no necesitas volver a referenciarlo dentro el `setState`. Además no entiendo lo que estás buscando con la sintaxis de los paréntesis cuadrados para cambiar tu estado, pero no lo necesitas.

Lo correcto sería algo similar a esto:

```
const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
  setState({
    checkedFilter: !state.checkedFilter
  });
};
```

Mira que no uso el evento para manejar el estado del componente, esto es porque según lo que veo quieres hacer un [Componente Controlado de React](https://www.escuelafrontend.com/articulos/las-diferencias-entre-componentes-controlados-y-no-controlados-en-react), si estás usando está técnica apegate a ella. En palabras sencillas, el estado de tu checkbox es manejado por React por medio de tus hooks en este caso y no necesitas acceder a algo como `event.target.value` ya que el verdadero estado de tu componente no está almacenado en el elemento del DOM de manera directa.